# getting http debug info

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, http.client

I'm going through Dive into Python3.  When I get to the chapter on http web services section 14.4, I can't seem to duplicate the following output in the python3 shell.  Here's what the sample code looks like:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen('http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml')

send: b'GET /examples/feed.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: diveintopython3.org
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.1'
Connection: close
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
…further debugging information omitted…
```

When I enter this in ipython3, the final command gives no output.  So why am I not getting the debug info in the example?  After entering the above code, response.debuglevel == 0.  I'm using python3.5.2.

Comment: you should be setting your debug level on HTTPConnection, not on response

Comment: And you should use `urllib2.urlopen()` since `urllib` got deprecated in Python3: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: @alfasin That's wrong per your own link: "Also note that the urllib.request.urlopen() function in Python 3 is equivalent to urllib2.urlopen() and that urllib.urlopen() has been removed."

Comment: @alfasin That's exactly what I'm saying, you're not reading that correctly. It's saying "the urllib.request.urlopen() function in Python 3 is equivalent to urllib2.urlopen() [in Python 2] and that urllib.urlopen() has been removed [from Python 3]." `urllib` is absolutely still in python (see: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.html) and `urllib2` isn't a module in Python 3.

Comment: @Jakub you're right - my bad!

Answer (score 2):

The final command should not give any output, what you probably want is:

```
print(response.read())
```

Comment: It gives the debug output shown in the question when I run the python code on my laptop.  I checked the docs you link.  urllib got split into urllib.request, urllib.parse, and urllib.error.  It seems that urllib2 is actually deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old question, bit I thought I would answer to help those who might still be seeing this question.*

Ever since Python version 3.5.2 (release ~June 2016) the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` is entirely ignored in favor of the `debuglevel` constructor argument for `urllib.request.HTTPHandler`.

This is due to [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9642eedc0a6d90d9502658a6569518741eea9ef3) change that sets the value of `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` to whatever is set in `urllib.request.HTTPHandler`'s constructor argument `debuglevel`, on [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Lib/urllib/request.py#L1224) line.

A [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99353) has been opened to fix this, but in the mean time you can either do one of two things:

1. You can use the constructor argument for `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` (as demonstrated in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876579/python-3-urllib-and-http-client-unable-to-turn-on-debug-messages/42878015#42878015)):

   ```py
   import urllib.request

   handler = urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=10)
   opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
   content = opener.open('http://stackoverflow.com').read()

   print(content[0:120])
   ```
2. You can also monkey patch the `__init__` methods of `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` to respect the global values like so:

   ```py
   https_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__

   def https_new_init(self, debuglevel=None, context=None, check_hostname=None):
       debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
       https_old_init(self, debuglevel, context, check_hostname)

   urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__ = https_new_init

   http_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__

   def http_new_init(self, debuglevel=None):
       debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
       http_old_init(self, debuglevel)

   urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__ = http_new_init
   ```

   Note: I don't recommend setting the `debuglevel` in `HTTPHandler`'s as a method argument default value because the default values for method arguments get evaluated at function definition evaluation time, which, for `HTTPHandler`'s constructor, is when the module `urllib.request` is imported.