# Verbose logging for urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Is there any way to enable some kind of verbose logging for urllib? I'm especially trying to find out which TLS-Cert files its using and which proxy its using. I.e. if it is actually using what I configured in the env.

Answer (score 0):

In Python version 3.5.1 and earlier, you can do this two ways:

1. You can use the constructor argument for `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` (as demonstrated in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876579/python-3-urllib-and-http-client-unable-to-turn-on-debug-messages/42878015#42878015)):

   ```py
   import urllib.request

   handler = urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=10)
   opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
   content = opener.open('http://example.com').read()

   print(content[0:120])
   ```
2. You can set the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` class variable to enable logging for all future connections.

   ```py
   import urllib.request
   import http.client

   http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
   content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com').read()

   print(content[0:120])
   ```

In Python version 3.5.2 and later, the second method no longer works (the first one still works fine though). To use the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` class variable, you will need to monkey patch the `__init__` methods of `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` like so (at least until [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/99353) PR is merged and back-ported):

```py
https_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__

def https_new_init(self, debuglevel=None, context=None, check_hostname=None):
    debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
    https_old_init(self, debuglevel, context, check_hostname)

urllib.request.HTTPSHandler.__init__ = https_new_init

http_old_init = urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__

def http_new_init(self, debuglevel=None):
    debuglevel = debuglevel if debuglevel is not None else http.client.HTTPSConnection.debuglevel
    http_old_init(self, debuglevel)

urllib.request.HTTPHandler.__init__ = http_new_init
```

(*Note: I don't recommend setting the `debuglevel` in `HTTPHandler`'s as a method argument default value because the default values for method arguments get evaluated at function definition evaluation time, which, for `HTTPHandler`'s constructor, is when the module `urllib.request` is imported.*)

The reason why you have to do this (if you want to use the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` class variable as a global value) is because of a [change](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9642eedc0a6d90d9502658a6569518741eea9ef3) that was introduced beginning Python 3.5.2 that [sets](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9642eedc0a6d90d9502658a6569518741eea9ef3#diff-1b72fd8dc0aaa51a5ba3af938d3e3bdea8ab5635c0c2d9e098f9825f5b47b03fR1214) the `http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel` *instance* variable (which normally just shadows the respective class variable) to the whatever the value is for the `debuglevel` constructor argument on the `HTTPHandler` and `HTTPSHandler` classes, irrespective of whether the argument is set or not. Because it defaults to `0`, the `HTTPConnection.debuglevel` instance variable will always be overridden, by either the value passed to the constructor, or the default, `0`.